# Spring + Thymeleaf + ElementProcessor + @autowired not working

Tags: spring, autowired, thymeleaf

I am trying to use @Autowired within an ElementProcessor.
( http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/extendingthymeleaf.html#some-reasons-to-extend-thymeleaf )

```
@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
public class AuditLogElementProcessor extends AbstractMarkupSubstitutionElementProcessor {
  @Autowired(required = true)
  DocumentService docService;
```

But somehow the object docService is always null.
The code itself is definetely working. 
I already tried it with LTW and it was working with the exact same code(but I'm not allowed to use LTW).

Do you have any ideas how I can inject my Service into my ElementProcessor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

Found it out myself.
The problem was that the ElementProcessor could not access the Services because the Processors are only created when needed.

Solution:
Autowire all the Services you need in the Dialect (that creates the Processors) and pass all the Services as parameters to the Processors.

It works this way